# Load images dynamically in ASP.Net page using C# and change another image on click of previous image on client side

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

i want to add dynamically images in asp.net using C#. after this i want to change image as selected on client side click event. i do not know for this what i will use. please anybody solve my problem. for problem reference: huitsuit dashboard lending page.

Answer (score 0):

Create new Page which should create image runtime as follows:

```
string s = Server.MapPath("original.jpg");
string s2 = Server.MapPath("ikon.gif");

System.Drawing.Image original= Bitmap.FromFile(s);
Graphics gra = Graphics.FromImage(original);
Bitmap logo = new Bitmap(s2);
gra.DrawImage(logo, new Point(70, 70));

Response.ContentType = "image/JPEG";
big.Save(Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Now in your existing page Implement `ICallBack` interface
( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178208.aspx )

in response of ICallback interface you can set image source to you image aspx page.
e.g
<image src='Image.aspx'>